# Stying in React-tag-input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using "React-tag-input" [react-tag-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tag-input).

But can't find how to do styling of react-tag-input

my code looks like this

```
      import { WithContext as ReactTags } from 'react-tag-input';

     const App = React.createClass({
      getInitialState() {
        return {
        tags: [],
        suggestions: []
         }
      },

 handleDelete(i) {
      let tags = this.state.tags;
      tags.splice(i, 1);
      this.setState({tags: tags});
     },

handleAddition(tag) {
    let tags = this.state.tags;
    tags.push({
        id: tags.length + 1,
        text: tag
    });
    this.setState({tags: tags});
},

handleDrag(tag, currPos, newPos) {
    let tags = this.state.tags;
    tags.splice(currPos, 1);
    tags.splice(newPos, 0, tag);
    this.setState({ tags: tags });
},


render() {
    let tags = this.state.tags;
    let suggestions = this.state.suggestions;
    return (
        <div>
```

I am looking for styling in ReactTags

```
                <ReactTags tags={tags}
                suggestions={suggestions}
                handleDelete={this.handleDelete}
                handleAddition={this.handleAddition}
                handleDrag={this.handleDrag} />
        </div>
       )
     }
 });

  ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Can you guide me, how to do styling in this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS. From [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tag-input#styling):

> `<ReactTags>` does not come up with any styles. However, it is very easy to customize the look of the component the way you want it. By default, the component provides the following classes with which you can style -
>
> - ReactTags__tags
> - ReactTags__tagInput
> - ReactTags__tagInputField
> - ReactTags__selected
> - ReactTags__selected ReactTags__tag
> - ReactTags__selected ReactTags__remove
> - ReactTags__suggestions

So, if you want to change the background of a tag, you could do something like this in your CSS:

```
.ReactTags__tag {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Example Styles for React Tags*/
#app {
  padding: 40px;
}

div.ReactTags__tags {
    position: relative;
}

/* Styles for the input */
div.ReactTags__tagInput {
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.ReactTags__tagInput input.ReactTags__tagInputField,
div.ReactTags__tagInput input.ReactTags__tagInputField:focus {
    height: 31px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

/* Styles for selected tags */
div.ReactTags__selected span.ReactTags__tag {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    background: #eee;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    cursor: default !important;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
div.ReactTags__selected a.ReactTags__remove {
    color: #9c9c9c;
    margin-left: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Styles for suggestions */
div.ReactTags__suggestions {
    position: absolute;
    color: #000 !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
}
div.ReactTags__suggestions ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    box-shadow: .05em .01em .5em rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    background: white;
    width: 200px;
}
div.ReactTags__suggestions li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
div.ReactTags__suggestions li mark {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background: none;
    font-weight: 600;
}
div.ReactTags__suggestions ul li.ReactTags__activeSuggestion {
    background: #b7cfe0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! When writing an answer it is immensely useful for people reading you answer, when you not only provide the code that solves the problem in the question, but also explain what your code does. Otherwise it becomes very hard for someone not familiar with the technologies involved to understand why your code does what it does and in turn modify it for their own needs.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable message.